# Subtracting from div height in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

today I have a quick question.  Here is my function:

```
function checkheight() {
var heightofdiv = $('#checkforheight').height();
$("#centeredbackground").css("min-height",heightofdiv);
}
```

My problem is that I want to get my variable, heightofdiv, and then subtract the answer by 42 pixels.  So really, I want heightofdiv to be equal to the height of checkforheight minus 42 pixels.  If this is even possible, help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand...Can you explain?

Comment: You should use the jquery arithmetic plugin: `var heightofdiv = $.subtract($('#checkforheight').height(), 42);` [found here](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not simply subtract 42 from `$('#checkforheight').height()`?

```
var heightofdiv = $('#checkforheight').height() - 42;
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of but I don't know if this is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you from just doing this?

```
$('#checkforheight').height() - 42;
```

Comment: My n00bishness of jquery.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what your looking for.

$("#centeredbackground").css("min-height",(heightofdiv - 42));